# Render PDF from JSON - table with subtotals at pagebreak

Tags: javascript, json, pdf

I am developing a WebApp with NODE.js

I need to render a PDF from a JSON file that could look something like this:

```
{"Items": 
    [{"Position": "Bananas", "Price": "5.50"},
     {"Position": "Grapes", "Price": "8.50"},
     {"Position": "Apples", "Price": "1.80"},
     {"Position": "Pineapples", "Price": "9.30"},
     {"Position": "Tomatoes", "Price": "2.70"}]}
```

I want to build a table like shown in the first picture. At the end of each page, the subtotal is shown when the page would break.

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIaIv.png)

And at the beginning of the next page the subtotal should also be shown again. At the end of the table the actual total should be shown:

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVelX.png)

Does anyone have a suggestion how i could do this, or which library to use?